# Is it ok to play games in office pc?

Tags: work-environment

I have installed a computer game on my office machine. After the working hours, I am playing games.

Is this ethically ok? Or am I misusing my freedom in my workplace?

Comment: What does your company policy say? Some companies don't care what you install on your work computer. Others simply have rules that you must only install legally obtained software. And others don't let you install any unapproved software at all. If you aren't sure, talk to your manager.

Comment: Are you working in game journalism or game development where playing games is part of your job?

Comment: this begs the qeustion why are you at work after working hours? And is it a legal copy of the game?

Comment: Installing any unauthorized software on your work PC would be a huge infringement of policies at every company I've worked at.

Comment: @Raoul yes. I do play after working hours. It is not a legal copy.

Comment: @CrazyNinja Even the most relaxed rules I've ever seen on personal use of workstations prohibit installing unlicensed software.

Comment: @CrazyNinja just saaaay it's legal bro come on!

Comment: The fact that you are installing illegal copies on your work machine most likely has security implications, too. Not a good idea, even if we assume illegal copying is ethical.

Comment: Most organizations disapprove installing games because most of the time people download "free" or illegal software that are loaded with virus and malware.

Comment: are we being trolled again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most workplaces this would be a big no-no, and probably a terminable offense if you were to be found out.

Your company owns the machine, the software running on it, and has the right to read every file on it. They could legally keep track of every key you push, even so far as storing your personal passwords if you input them on your work machine - most places *don't*, but they *could*.

By installing software they're not aware of you're opening the door to potential security threats, or legal liability (is the game pirated, for example?)

Furthermore, it's a game. Most employers will take a very dim view of their employees using their work machines to run video games.

Now, you may work for a very informal, or friendly sort of person who OK's this sort of thing, but the fact that you're asking this question makes me believe that you've done this behind your boss's back, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Its worth noting that surveillance of employees on company machines is largely illegal in most of the EU, so there they can't know what websites you visit, and certainly can't know your passwords, without your prior written consent (which can not be used as reason not to hire or as reason to fire). IANAL though

Comment: "probably a fireable offense" Bit mute since an at will employee can be fired anyways so even if it wasnt they still could. Also the fact that he can install games is a bad Management of his user rights.

Comment: @RaoulMensink - I'm not an "at will" employee. Maybe you are, and that's fine, but my comment makes perfect sense in the context of my own experience. Had the OP provided more information maybe it would read differently.

Comment: @RaoulMensink Stick to your guns man, everyone who posts here is subject to American labor law.  Even people from Sri Lanka.

Comment: @Myles Eh? I'm most definitely not subject to American labour law and I'm pretty sure that many others here are not either...

Comment: @MarvMills - myles was making a sarcastic comment because Raoul is not accounting for anyone else not working in the US.

Comment: @AndreiROM, Myles I am not subject to at will employement, but there are different forms of that over the entire world. Calling it "at will" is just simpler in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

In situations like this, I find the best rule of thumb is "Am I asking an anonymous internet community or my line manager for clarification of whether is this okay"...

More seriously, unless you have a job where you are simply required to be in your place of work for periods of time in case something happens (like a night guard or something), then you are using work's resources to play computer games. Unless you've explicitly been told that's okay, it probably isn't.

Go ask your manager.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this 10 times so it was higher than the other answers which make gross assumptions rather than giving the correct answer, which is that this is 100% company-specific (which, of course, is why the question was put on hold).

Answer (score 6):

The phrase "wrong on so many levels" comes to mind.

A place I worked for would fire you for attaching a smart phone to your machine to charge.

Get the game off ASAP and hope they don't already know.

1. It's misuse of company property
2. It's introducing unauthorized software to a company machine
3. It's a breach of trust between you and your manager
4. It's a security risk
5. It's setting yourself up to be terminated for any of the above reasons.

Plus, it just plain looks bad.  There's a game on your system.  Now PROVE you haven't been playing it on company time.  You can't.  That, my friend is a problem.

When I've been management, I've actually been pretty forgiving about such things, but I'm the exception, not the rule.  Most employers will assume you've just been slacking.

Now, even if you've been doing it after work, you are still using company property in an unauthorized fashion.  There is no way you look good in this matter.

Get a smart phone and play games on that.  Keep the company equipment clean.